# Properly bind Javascript events

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am looking for the most proper and efficient way to **bind Javascript events**; particularly the `onload` event (I would like the event to occur **after both the page AND all elements such as images** are loaded). I know there are simple ways to do this in jQuery but I would like the more efficient **raw Javascript** method.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There are two different ways to do it. Only one will work; which one depends on the browser. Here's a utility method that uses both:

```
function bindEvent(element, type, handler) {
   if(element.addEventListener) {
      element.addEventListener(type, handler, false);
   } else {
      element.attachEvent('on'+type, handler);
   }
}
```

In your case:

```
bindEvent(window, 'load', function() {
    // all elements such as images are loaded here
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Very thorough and exactly what I'm looking for!

Comment: @Jackie: the fun doesn't end here. See my answer.

Comment: The event itself is a dependency that can be avoided in large part by understanding DOM. DOM loads in a top-to-bottom fashion; items nearer the top of the document load earlier while items toward the end later. By loading scripts that have DOM dependencies at the end of your document many of these concerns can be mitigated with no event binding at all. Keep it simple.

Comment: @KingRider: Which browser and version?

Comment: @DavidHedlund newest version with win 10 to Internet Explorer

Comment: @KingRider: Internet Explorer 11 doesn't have `element.attachEvent` but it has `element.addEventListener` so if your code is exactly as above, it shouldn't hit that `else` clause. Verify that `element` is indeed a html node (and not, say, a jQuery wrapped element, but then I guess you're not using jQuery if you're using this code at all)

Comment: @DavidHedlund not used jquery, but need jquery? topic tag just javascript =S .. i know jquery ´.bind()` ... i need javascript pure

Comment: Yeah, you shouldn't need jQuery. IE 11 has `addEventListener`.

Answer (score 20):

I know you did only ask about how to bind events. But Ooooo boy the fun doesn't end there. There's a lot more to getting this right cross-browser than just the initial binding.

@d.'s answer will suffice just fine for the specific case of the `load` event of `window` you're looking for. But it may give novice readers of your code a false sense of "getting it right". Just because you bound the event doesn't mean you took care to normalize it. You may be better of *just* fixing `window.onload`:

```
window.onload = (function(onload) {
  return function(event) {
    onload && onload(event);

    // now do your thing here
  }
}(window.onload))
```

But for the general case of event binding @d.'s answer is so far from satisfying as to be frustrating. About the only thing it does right is use feature-detection as opposed to browser detection.

Not to go on too much of a rant here but JavaScript event binding is probably *the* #1 reason to go with a JavaScript library. I don't care which one it is, other people have fixed this problem over and over and over again. Here're the issues in a home-brewed implementation once inside your handler function:

- How do I get a hold of the `event` object itself?
- How do I prevent the default action of the event (eg clicking on a link but not navigating)
- Why does `this` point to the `window` object all the time?
- (Re mouse events) What are the x/y coords of the event?
- Which mouse button triggered the event?
- Was it a Ctrl-click or just a regular click?
- What element was the event actually triggered on?
- What element is the event going *to*? (ie `relatedTarget`, say for `blur`)
- How do I cancel the bubbling of the event up through its parent DOM?
- (Re event bubbling) what element is actually receiving the event now? (ie `currentTarget`)
- Why can't I get the freaking char code from this `keydown` event?
- Why is my page leaking memory when I add all these event handlers?? Argh!
- Why can't I Unbind this anonymous function I bound earlier?

And the list goes on...

The only good reason to roll your own in these days is for learning. And that's fine. Still,  read PPK's [Intro to browser events](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html). Look at the [jQuery source](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js). Look at the [Prototype source](http://prototypejs.org/assets/2009/8/31/prototype.js). You won't regret it.

Comment: There are instances where loading a **library** or **framework** are impractical and are overkill for any number of reasons (early vs late loading, bloat of js for "simple functionality", ...).

Answer (score 6):

Something like that

```
window.onload = (function(onload) {
    return function(event) {
        onload && onload(event);

        $(".loading-overlay .spinner").fadeOut(300),
            $(".loading-overlay").fadeOut(300);
            $("body").css({
                overflow: "auto",
                height: "auto",
                position: "relative"
            })
    }
}(window.onload));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
window.onload = function() {
   // ...
};
```