# javascript Document ready firefox (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, firefox, document, ready

In FireFox I have this jQuery at the end of the body:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $.getScript('LiveMapsJavascriptProvider.aspx?type=reference&value=6', init);
});
```

There are a lot of js files in the head that are needed to be all loaded before this would work. So I put my call in a document.ready event. It doesn't work. IE works fine.

If I put an alert(''); before I call $.getScript it works.

It looks like a problem with the scripts not getting loaded yet?

I thought Document.ready was fired after all the scripts are loaded and ready to go.

Thanks,
ian

Comment: Use the "network" tab in Firebug to see whether the aspx file gets loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't necessarily need to use jQuery for that.

Simply have an onload function as below:

```
<body onload="JavascriptFunctionName">
```

Or you can dynamically attach your function call to the onload event as shown below:

```
function addEvent(obj, evType, fn){ 
 if (obj.addEventListener){ 
   obj.addEventListener(evType, fn, false); 
   return true; 
 } else if (obj.attachEvent){ 
   var r = obj.attachEvent("on"+evType, fn); 
   return r; 
 } else { 
   return false; 
 } 
}
addEvent(window, 'load', JavascriptFunctionName);
```

You may embed jQuery functions calls inside the `JavascriptFunctionName` function.

**EDIT**:

jQuery is also capable of doing that through the following code. I recommend trying that first, for the sake of avoiding unnecessary redundant code.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    JavascriptFunctionName();
});
```

Comment: Because that's what I could provide to help OP. If you find any bug in the implementation of the addEvent function, please let me know. Upvotes/Downvotes should relate to how helpful the answer was, and I believe it was. You are free to go ahead and post a better answer.

Comment: OP is evidently using jQuery already for `$.getScript`. Why in cripes would you recommend rolling another half-baked `addEvent` implementation when jQuery has this all wrapped up with `$(window).load(init)`? Binding the event is just the tip of the x-browser-event-ugly-iceberg: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796141/properly-bind-javascript-events/1796729#1796729

Comment: It's not half-baked, it works perfectly and this is where it gains its value. Nonetheless, I understand the notion of unnecessary redundant code, so I've amended my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

`document.ready` is fired after the DOM is loaded. You may try this:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    // will execute once all scripts and images are finished loading
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using something like [head.js](http://headjs.com) to specify execution order, while still taking advantage of parallel loading.