# can this be done without jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I show the alert when I have scrolled to the right 300px?

```
$('.container').scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scroll() === 300) { //
        alert("You've scrolled 300 pixels.");
    }
});
```

Can I get some help getting a callback without using jquery?

Comment: See this for binding events in JavaScript ->  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796141/properly-bind-javascript-events

Comment: If you can do it with jquery, then you can *always* do it with pure javascript. It's just likely to be more difficult. A better title would probably be "How can this be done without jquery?"

Answer (score 0):

You can bind to the onscroll method:

```
window.onscroll = function() {
    if (window.pageYOffset == 300) {
        alert("You've scrolled 300 pixels.");
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the onscroll event just like the onclick on element.